# Code doesn't work on iPhone but works on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this code in my live chat.

```
if (TRUE && (balloonsOn != NO || !htmlStart)) {
    balloonsOn  = TRUE;


    htmlStart = [self createChatLines: balloonsOn ? @"htmlformat-balloons" : @"htmlformat"];

    if (chatLines > 0){
        chatLines = 0;
        [self updateView];
    }   
}
```

On the simulator it works fine but on the phone it doesn't work. It has worked before many times but now it stopped working on the phone. Why is this happening?

Comment: Thats the issue. When I run it on the simulator I get no error. Even when I plug in my phone and run it it works. When I test my app on the phone without running it from the simulator it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there should be nothing that wouldn't work on the iPhone.. The only thing I can suppose, is you are using that strings without caring of the case-sensitiveness of iOs. The simulator is case insensitive but iOs is.. Let me know :)

Comment: Also change 'TRUE' with 'YES'

Comment: Are you saying that these strings `@"htmlformat-balloons" : @"htmlformat"` need to be case-sensitive? I have them as spelt the exact same way I have them in my project. Also changing `TRUE` to `YES` did not work

Comment: I think there are not enough elements to say what's going wrong here... Try edit the question adding the code of updateView and  createChatLines.

Comment: createChatLines had a capital A in one of my strings. Im surprised that this error didn't happen earlier

Answer (score 0):

What is the variable 'TRUE' ? I think having that as a variable name is probably the issue, rename it something else and see if it works.